# embedded vimeo not loading

Tags: iframe, moodle, vimeo

I've embedded a lot of videos in my moodle page. Some of them are not loading at all or talkig forever to load. Sorry for posting a stupid question, but I just don't know what to do.

Could there be something in the iframe that is causing problems:

```
<center>
  <div class="video-max-size">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/116054472?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" frameborder="0" width="500" height="281"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Any tip would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to install a filter. So when you embed the vimeo code it plays correctly. There is a plug in over here:

https://moodle.org/plugins/view/filter_vimeoembed

Comment: Thank you! I'm just checking it out.